# Dropbox functionality within php webpage

Tags: php, web-applications, dropbox

I have a website that runs on php and mySQL. I wish to create a page on this website that lists the files and folders of my DropBox. The php code should also be able to access the files and folders on dropbox. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes.  Dropbox has [an API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers).

Comment: I haven't tried anything as I have very little idea how to approach the problem yet. But even with the API, how would I create a folder on my server (it is being hosted by a web hosting provider) that is 'dropbox' active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just follow this [document](http://code.google.com/p/dropbox-php/wiki/Dropbox_API) , hope it will helps you.

or

also you can refer this [source code](https://github.com/Dropbox-PHP/dropbox-php)